# Node and Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to learn to connect to postgresql from Node and run queries. I am getting a "TypeError: dbh.query is not a function" error. Any idea why? I've tried several different ways of connecting and running queries from reading several tutorials and I keep getting this error.

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

try{

const dbh = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'blog',
    password: 'skippy1985',
    port: 5432,
  });

dbh.connect();
}catch(error){
    console.log('error connecting to postgres' + error);
}

router.use(bodyParser.json()); 
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post('/user/createUser', function (req, res) {
    var resp;
    var user = ({username:req.body.username, email:req.body.email, password:req.body.password});
    saltRounds = 14;
    try{
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, saltRounds);
        dbh.query(
            'INSERT INTO blog(username, email, password) VALUES ('+ user.username +','+ user.email + ',' + hash,
            (err, userData) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    esp = {"status": "ok"};
                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(resp));
                }else{
                    resp = {"error": err};
                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(resp));
                }
                client.end();
        }); 
    }catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: It means `new Client` threw an exception. Check your console that logs an error.

Comment: The error I described is the only error in the console. Did I structure the try/catch correctly?

Comment: It's another error. There should also be `console.log('error connecting to postgres' + error);` output.

Comment: I commented out the first try/catch and now the error gone and it's working. Why is the try/catch blocking my connection?

Comment: It's not possible to say without that other error message. `try-catch` there is for a reason and must be kept.